# Using jQuery themes (CSS) within jsFiddle

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jsfiddle

Has anyone tried using any of the jQuery themes in jsFiddle?

I'm interested in using the Accordion widget with a theme but having 
trouble implementing it in jsFiddle. The trouble is, I believe the themes require 
image files to populate some of its effects, and my suspicion is that 
jsFiddle has some sort of issue with that. I even resorted to 
uploading the custom css and js files from the jquery download, along 
with all the images, onto my personal home server and adding them as 
managed resources. I'm getting the functionality, but not the desired 
imagery.

Here's my current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mendahu/CmX4k/

To see what it should be like, checked jQuery's "Humanity" theme on the UI site.

The managed resources are found here:

https://robins.homeserver.com/home/jquerycourse/ (also the images subdirectory).

As far as I can tell, the directory structure is the same (ie. the CSS 
document refers to all images as "images/whatever.png"), and I 
organized it as such on my server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow.  Is that information displayed public knowledge?  I personally can't do much with a name/DOB/phone number, but others might.<br />
Sorry if my paranoia is out of line.
<br /><br />
**Clarification:** the information displayed in the jsFiddle, not in your question.

Comment: Heh, it's not real data. Check out http://www.generatedata.com

Comment: This fiddle was posted in the jsFiddle google group: 

http://jsfiddle.net/charlesemerson/Ese2k/ 

It uses jquery themes no problem. I can't figure it out; the only 
difference was that instead of using his own managed resources, he 
simply used the jsfiddle UI selector, and then posted google versions 
of the css docs. I ported them to my fiddle and now it works (though I 
have some other problems now :). 

The file heirarchy is still the same (all images are pointing to 
images/whatever.png). Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

The fiddle that successfully uses the theme that you linked to in your comments references the required jQuery ui css files.

Have a look in the 'Managed Resources' tab on the left of the fiddle and you will see a couple of files called 'jquery-ui.css'. If you hover over each of them, you'll see that one of them references the base jquery themes css file and the other references a theme file (both of these files are the ones stored at googleapis.com). That's all you need to do.

[See this page for a link to the google hosted themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348559/are-there-hosted-jquery-ui-themes-anywhere)